# How to get firstindex of array in struct Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, codable

Hi I have a struct like this

```
struct OrderCaches: Codable {
    var food, drink: [Food]?
}


struct Food: Codable{
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var quantity: Double?
    var notes: String?
}
```

I want to get first index where id = productList[indexPath.row].id

I tried with:

```
let index = OrderCaches.firstIndex(where: {$0.food.id == productList[indexPath.row].id})
```

but not work I get this error "**Value of type '[Food]?' has no member 'id'**".
How can I get the first Index?
Thanks

Comment: The types here are really suspicious. What does it mean to have a `nil` quantity of a an unnamed `Food` with no ID or notes? Because that's currently possible given the types of the fields of `Food`, but it doesn't make any sense in real life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `firstIndex` is not a static member, but an instance member, hence you have to create an instance of `OrderCache` to get the index, like below:

```swift
let orderCaches = OrderCaches(food: [], drink: [])
let index = orderCaches.food?.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == productList[indexPath.row].id })
```

Comment: sorry i just realise you posted the same solution before me .. so deleted mine

Comment: @jawadAli Oh, that's fine. It's always good to have a second opinion, happy coding.

Comment: I found a solution. My mistake was that I have create a variable of type [OrderCaches]. Now variable is of type "OrderCaches", now it works. Thanks for solutions